# Listview style Each Row

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, custom-adapter

this is the code in my custom adapter (THE CODE IN BROWN COLOR) when initially list is build proper margin is applied to valid items when i scroll down and again scroll up all the rows in list shifts the margin left by 20 what i'm doing wrong please reply soon

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        // getting data
        final ViewMovieDetailsModel_ViewComments movies = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.comment_row, null);                
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            //getting handles

            holder.comments_linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments_linearLayout);
            holder.commenter_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_row_commenter);
            holder.commented_on_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_row_comment_time);
            holder.comment_text_textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_row_comment_text);
            holder.reply_button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_row_reply_button);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (movies != null) 
        {
            if (((movies.getParent_comment_id()).toString().equals("null")) && session.isLoggedIn()==true) {
                holder.reply_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                holder.reply_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


`if (!((movies.getParent_comment_id()).toString().equals("null"))) 
{

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    params.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.comments_linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
}`


            holder.commenter_textView.setText(movies.getUsername_commentor());

            holder.commenter_textView.setTag(movies.getUser_id_commentor());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: use a custom listview with a custom adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan i'm using custom listview with custom adapter

Comment: @Tom Reznik posted entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are setting margins (the brown font) in 'if' statement:

```
if (movies != null)
```

just take it out of this if block (for example put it just before the return point)

Right now this code is probably not executed at the first view load, since the movie is null. When the getView is called second time, the movie is not null, and the marigin is set according to your 'brown' code.

if this is not the solution - maybe the inside if statement condition is not true (the one that is in first 'brown' row). so.. your own logic prevents the marigins to be set as you want :)

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: doesn't help i assure u that IF condition i mentioned here is correct

when first called the rows are set according to above given condition

but when i scroll down and scroll up all the rows accqure same style

please help i'm stuck at this for so long

Comment: I strongly recommend taing the Layout params settings out of very if, and place it right before return point. Just to try - it costs nothing. views in ListView are reused. So they are not being built from scratch every time. This is probably the reason why you have coditions like movie != null.

Comment: or event simplier evidence: in 'brown' block of code place some breakpoint or log statement and check if it gets executed each time you expect it to

Comment: I am not sure if I see corectly - does your return statement is in if(movies != null) block?

Comment: thanx for help and for ur time too. I used (@Android Noob way) I am using Transparent image `VIEW.Gone` by default and when condition meet `VIEW.Visible`. Got it working (but don't know why Layout params not working)    If u have some time can u please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser/17390977#17390977

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about solving this problem is instead of using `LayoutParams.setMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)`, you could create an empty `TextView` whose width is `20 dp` by default and whose position will be to the left of your rows contents.  It will be `View.GONE` by default, but when `if (!((movies.getParent_comment_id()).toString().equals("null")))` happens, you can set that to `View.VISIBLE`

Comment: i want whole linear layout of row to have margin not only specifically textview.

can u pls provide me a way